# How to display the 2d lidar (pointcloud) data in rviz?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hai , i would like to display the 2d lidar (pointcloud) data in rviz,
if way is there pls say how to do it ..

thanks,
younus.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67623/how-to-display-the-2d-lidar-(pointcloud)-data-in-rviz?/) by [YOUNUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/5450/younus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-17

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This type of update should be added as an edit to your question, so that everybody who reads your question sees it immediately. As an answer, it's hidden down here at the bottom =)

Also - have you read the rviz docs: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide? What part doesn't make sense?

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1